# Toggle Start/Stop in Angular and post the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to add a status button Start/Stop which receives status from json and show it on the button. If the status is "start"  it toggles to green button. If the status is "stop" 
red button is visible. Also on button click the start status turns stop and vice-versa and the status is sent.

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"  ng-controller="DataCtrl" >
     <form class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" ng-repeat="state in datas" >

     <button type="button" ng-show ="isSet()" ng-click="setStatus()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">{{state.status}}</button>
     </form>
```

I tried http://plnkr.co/edit/jw0dpxZRFtkyqA1nwMuO?p=preview but I am unable to handle the data binding here. How to check for the status and toggle?

P.S. I am new to angular. Help me learn.

Comment: tried the suggested answer, mark as accepted if helps

Comment: Thanks. I set a variable on scope binded to ng-show.

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking on 'v' and making it green. this is how you accept answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2460773

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple example you can learn from:
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DQsAKkjfuoqZGiuVJnvR?p=preview)

the main idea is to set a variable on scope, and set it when the buttons are clicked.
also you give a class depending on that variable value:

```
<button type="button" 
        ng-click="status = !status" 
        class="btn btn-lg" 
        ng-class="{'btn-success' : status, 'btn-danger' : !status}">
```

the same applies when you want to show/hide elements